# Is there a way to iterate over multiple dataframes to write them to multiple excel sheets with formatting?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in pandas with 8 data frames and wish to write each of them to their own sheet in an Excel workbook.  I also would like to apply formatting to each of the sheets as well.  I am able to do it if I copy and paste the code 8 times, and adjust for the sheet name.  However I was attempting to clean up the code by using a for loop to iterate through my data frames.  However I end up with the: 
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Excel_Test.xlsx') as writer:
    df_list = [df_1 ,df_2 ,df_3 ,df_4 ,df_5 ,df_6 ,df_7 ,df_8]   
    for sheet in df_list:
        sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet]
        worksheet.set_zoom(80)
        worksheet.set_column('A:A', 14)
        worksheet.set_column('B:B', 50)
        worksheet.set_column('C:C', 30)
        worksheet.set_column('D:D', 30)
        worksheet.set_column('E:E', 25)
        worksheet.set_column('F:F', 20)
        money_format = writer.book.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0'})
        integer_format = writer.book.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0'})
        worksheet.set_column('H:H', 9, integer_format)
writer.save()
```

The goal is to be able to have the for loop iterate through my list of dataframes and write each one to excel with the set formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sheet_name` parameter should be a string, not the `DataFrame` object. Since you use the `DataFrame` object as a key in the `writer.sheets` dictionary, Python is trying to hash that.